# CreateTimerQueueTimer's WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE flag while you can set a period of 0

Tags: c, winapi

I was reading [a man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-createtimerqueuetimer) about CreateTimerQueueTimer.

```
BOOL CreateTimerQueueTimer(
  PHANDLE             phNewTimer,
  HANDLE              TimerQueue,
  WAITORTIMERCALLBACK Callback,
  PVOID               DueTime,
  DWORD               Period,
  DWORD               Flags,
  ULONG               Parameter
);
```

The doc states:

> Period
>
> The period of the timer, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the timer is signaled once.

You can pass `flags` to this function, and one of the flags is `WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE`. I was wondering what was the purpose of this flag while you can just set a period of `0`.

Comment: The flag shows intent, that's self-documenting, unlike 0.